# onPrepareDialog deprecated

Tags: java, android, android-studio, deprecated

I picked someone android project up and I'm working on updating it and adding some new features for a future rerelease on the Play Store.
My issue right now is with dialogs. When the app was done three years ago, the guy who coded it used already deprecated methods. I've been able to fix them all except for one... here:

```
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog); // call super

    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        break;
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        ((TimePickerDialog) dialog).setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        break;
    }
}
```

problem is onPrepareDialog is deprecated and I want to fix it without having to change the whole class and its parents. Do you have any idea? I know that I need to use DialogFragment but I can't figure out how to do it efficiently without, like I said, doing the whole class again.
The class containing the code I posted extends a class that extends Activity. It also implements OnCheckedChangeListener.

Thanks

Comment: This code doesn't make sense to begin with. It's setting an OnDismissListener that dismisses a Dialog that's just been dismissed. There isn't even a reason to cast these objects because `setOnDismissListener` is a method of `Dialog`.

Comment: sometimes you just have to bite the bullet - cheers!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Comment: Problems from the app come from other .jar files dones by the other guy that didn't contain all the necessary file (how to mess up the next developper!) so after fixing it I'm able to "launch" the app. It builds but doesn't launch whole so I'll work on that from now on. Thanks!